# Object has no attribute in scikit-learn, how can I access it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, python-3.x, machine-learning

I would like to use different parameters of scikit's [SVC classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) with [cross-vlidation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), so I tried the following:

Then, let's use SVC algorithm:

```
from sklearn import svm
print('Support vector machine(SVM):   {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(
            y, stratified_cv(X, y, svm.SVC(kernel='linear')))))
```

But it seems I can not access to the object:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-dacd8d429376> in <module>()
      5 
      6 print('Support vector machine(SVM):   {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(
----> 7             y, stratified_cv(X, y, svm.SVC(kernel='linear')))))
      8 

AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'SVC'
```

Interestingly, when I try this:

```
print('Support vector machine(SVM):   {:.2f}'.format(metrics.accuracy_score(
            y, stratified_cv(X, y, svm.SVC))))
```

I get:

```
Support vector machine(SVM):   0.46
```

What could be happening?...any idea of given the above cross validation strategy, how to set up my own SVM configuration?. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Did you create an object called `svm` that is shadowing the `svm` module?

Comment: @BrenBarn, Thanks for the feedback. No, I added more details!

Comment: Then please show a self-contained example demonstrating the problem.  The variable `svm` is not defined in the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks again @BrenBarn, I edited with more details... sorry I am using jupyter

Comment: i'm not seeing where you defined `metrics`.

Comment: in the instance where you get the error, you're passing `stratified_cv` the output of `SVC`.  in the instance where you don't get the error, you're passing `stratified_cv` the function `SVC` itself.  these are two very different things.  it's really not surprising that your function works with one kind of input and not the other.  think some more about what you have here.

Comment: also, look at how much you have going on on the line that raises the error.  in order to isolate the causes of errors, you want distinct operations on different lines.

Comment: as it stands, this question deserves to be closed, because it has a lot of complicated BS that distracts from the core issue, which is a simple confusion about the difference between a function object and the return value of that function.  i'd say you should clean out all the extraneous `scikit` stuff here and keep only the pith of your real question, which is "what's the difference between `svm.SVC` and `svm.SVC(...)`?"

Comment: Thanks for the help @dbliss, I added the scikit stuff since the other user told me to add it... However, in regards to the pith of the problem I think that I do not understand how to setup SVC hyper parameters... Any idea of how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `partial` from python. In general, your function requires you to pass something that can be called with `clf_class(**kwargs)`, so if you pass a particular `object` (obtained through `clf = SVC(kernel='linear')`) it won't work, as you try to do

```
SVC(kernel='linear')(**kwargs) # error!
```

you want to call

```
SVC(kernel='linear', **kwargs)
```

so you can declare the partial function in python

```
from functools import partial
linear_svm = partial(svm.SVC, kernel='linear')
```

and now you can call

```
linear_svm(**kwargs)
```